# How to set CVS compression level

Tags: netbeans, cvs

I have read around that to speed up the CVS update process I can set the compression level.

I have access to the server(windows Env.) and I'm using the Netbeans as IDE.

But I still don't know how to set this configuration. Is it done on the server or on the client or both, and how?